# Implementing NSCoding protocol

Tags: objective-c, class, protocols, nscoding

I'm working on a obj-c project and I want to implement the NSCoding protocol for a class, but I can't get it right. The code looks like this:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class Object: NSObject, NSCoding {
    //Somecode
}
```

And I get the error: "Base specifier must name a class" and "Expected class name". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this swift or Objective-c?  If it is swift you shouldn't have the include, if it is objective-c is this a header file or implementation file?

Comment: It's Objective-C and it's a header file. The code before was  "class Object { //Somecode}" without the ": NSObject, NSCoding" and it worked well.

Comment: The syntax for adopting a protocol is `MyClass : NSObject <NSCoding>`, what you wrote is how to declare inheritance, and ObjC doesn't do multiple-inheritance, which is why you get an error.

Comment: I also tried writing it like that and then I get the errors: "Unknown template name 'NSObject'" and "Use of undeclared identifier 'NSCoding'"

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a `C++` class, not a `Objective-C` one, and you cannot have inheritance from one language to another. You'll need to change your class declaration to something like

```
@interface Object: NSObject <NSCoding> {
    // iVar declarations
}

// method and property declarations

@end
```

Although not sure how much it will help if your class already has defined `C++` methods, as you'll need to port those one to `Objective-C` definitions.

I highly recommend you go through the link I posted in my comments, and read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) on working with classes and objects. This will help you with the transition.